# How to group List by date to Map using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class called `Vote`:

```
public class Vote {
    private LocalDate date

    //getter and setter
}
```

I have two collections:

```
List<Vote> voteMap = new ArrayList<>();
Map<LocalDate, Integer> voteCountMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I need to group count of votes from the list to Map.
For example my List has next values:

```
Vote vote1 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,1));
Vote vote2 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,1));
Vote vote3 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,1));
Vote vote4 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,2));
Vote vote5 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,2));
Vote vote6 = new Vote(LocalDate.of(2019,1,3));
```

When I get my map and call the toString() method I must see something like this:

```
[{
    2019-1-1 : 3,
    2019-1-2 : 2,
    2019-1-3 : 1
}]
```

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) with [Collectors.counting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--)

```
Map<LocalDate, Long> result = votes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Vote::getDate, Collectors.counting()));
```